# Add new contact button in Einstein Activity Capture

Tags: contact, button, einstein, outlook

Hello,

I would like to add the "New Contact" button in Einstein Activity Capture on the user record.

Currently, there is only have the "New Lead" button and I don't know what I have to modify in Salesforce. A compact layout?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you have provided, it seems that you are using the Side Panel that is available either in Outlook or Gmail.

The reason why the **New Contact** button is not showing there is perhaps you have multiple Record Types available for the Contact Object. To move forward, you can visit your **New Contact** from **Global Actions** (in Setup) and make sure the **Record Type** field isn't set to **Master** (select a particular Record Type to be used).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem was the record type, thank you.